# How allow unathenticated users (guess) to access to aws appsync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync, federated-identity

I got a client API in aws appsync. Currently it has **AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS Authorization**, but I would like to allow unauthenticated users to access to some resources inside the GraphQL API. I am looking for some alternatives that does not include changing the way the API authorize access, **AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS Authorization** (Changing the authorization type is going to be my last option).

I am looking forward to authorizing cognito unauthenticated identities using **AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS Authorization**. Also if you considered that keep this type of authorization and trying to accomplish my use case is going to be the worst idea in the world, I would love to read your arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS AppSync does not support this use case yet. However, I'm happy to bring up your use case with the team and take it as a feature request :)

If you're interested, there is a good thread on [AWS Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=276886) that talks about this use case.

Comment: I have been following that thread but since the last good answer was in Apr 5, 2018 from Jeff. I was hoping there was a solution already.

Comment: We are working on various efforts to address these common use cases, you should see some updates in the near future.

Comment: Here is the RFC: https://github.com/aws/aws-appsync-community/issues/1. Feel free to provide your feedback.